# Include count = 0 in linq results

Tags: c#, linq, count

I have a table having `TeamName` and `CurrentStatus` fields. I am making a linq query to get for each team and for each status the count of records:

```
var teamStatusCounts = models.GroupBy(x => new { x.CurrentStatus, x.TeamName })
                             .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

The results of this query returns all the counts except where count is 0. I need to get the rows where there is no record for a specific team and a specific status (where count = 0).

Comment: Well, you can't create rows out of thin air.  Perhaps you have a separate table with all the teams listed. If so, you'll need to perform a left join between both tables. EDIT: And depending on your requirement, it may also be that you need to join on a table that contains all the possible statuses.

Comment: you have probably created the model by inner joining your status table and your teams right? then you will loose all status data in the results table. you can either change it to left join, or add empty rows at the end

Comment: Naively, something like `var teamStatusCounts = allPossibleStatusAndTeamCombinations.Select(x => new { Key = x, Count = models.Count(y => y.CurrentStatus == x.CurrentStatus && y.TeamName == x.TeamName), });`.

Comment: I'm surprised by all the upvotes.  OP has posted what is basically an unanswerable question until OP confirms if there is a master list of tables and/or statuses somewhere, and where this list exists (in code, in a database table, etc.)  And even then, more details will need to be provided about those lists/tables to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: The `models` object is an `IEnumerable<IssuesModel>` where `IssuesModel` is a view in the database. Basically, without these infos @konkked's answer has worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a separate collection for team name and statuses you are expecting and add the missing ones to the result set

```
//assuming allTeamNamesAndStatuses is a cross joing of all 'CurrentStatus' and 'TeamNames'
var teamStatusCounts = models.GroupBy(x => new { x.CurrentStatus, x.TeamName })
                             .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                             .ToList();

var missingTeamsAndStatuses = allTeamNamesAndStatuses
                   .Where(a=>
                      !teamStatusCounts.Any(b=>
                          b.Key.CurrentStatus == a.CurrentStatus 
                          && b.Key.TeamName == a.TeamName))
                   .Select(a=>new { 
                        Key = new {  a.CurrentStatus, a.TeamName  }, 
                        Count = 0 
                   });

teamStatusCounts.AddRange(emptyGroups);
```

[I've created a fiddle demonstrating the answer as well](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rSOP1V)

Answer (score 0):

I would select the team names and status first:

```
var teams = models.Select(x => x.TeamName).Distinct().ToList();
var status = models.Select(x => x.CurrentStatus).Distinct().ToList();
```

You can skip this if you know the list entries already.

Then you can select for each team and each state the number of models:

```
var teamStatusCounts = teams.SelectMany(team => states.Select(state =>
    new
    {
        TeamName = team,
        CurrentStatus = state,
        Count = models.Count(model =>
                    model.TeamName == team && model.CurrentStatus == state)
    }));
```

Comment: This can't work if `models` is missing team names and statuses to begin with, which is OP's problem.

Comment: @sstan I think you're right. I misunderstood the question. I thought there is always every team name and every state at least once in `models`.